# Conditional Probability with a double complement.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I understand that

1: $P(A|B)=P(A∩B)/P(B)$

and

2: $P(A∣B)=1−P(A′∣B)$

But what about

3: $P(A'|B')=$?

Comment: The desired formula might be $$P(A'\mid B')=1-\frac{P(A)-P(A\mid B)P(B)}{1-P(B)}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying your results, you can have

- $P(A'\mid B') = \dfrac{P(A'\cap B')}{P(B')}$
- $P(A'\mid B')=1- P(A\mid B')$

You could have something just in terms of $A$ and $B$:

- $P(A'\mid B') = \dfrac{1-P(A\cup B)}{1-P(B)}=1 - \dfrac{P(A)-P(A\cap B)}{1-P(B)}$

Comment: Interesting, and what would P(T|F')=

Comment: What are $T$ and $F$? Is $T=F'$?

Comment: P(T) = 0.7, P(F) = 0.6, also, for the question above, does it change anything if P(A) = 0.4 and P(B) = 0.3?

Comment: You will also need to know the probability of the intersection or another conditional probability

Comment: Ok. Well they are two different scenarios.

In P(A) P(B), P(A∩B) = 0.

In P(T) P(F), P(T∩F) = 0.55

Comment: From what I have written, you should be able to see $P(T|F')=\dfrac{P(T)-P(T\cap F)}{1-P(F)}$